# How do I display an array to a HTML page as a table when a button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a project due and specific things are needed. I am trying to display a table of an array to a HTML page from a js file when a button is pressed it should display the table. Here's what I got so far:

```js
function dundrumArray(){
    var dunMenu={
        OilleánTub:"¢3.50",
        DeluxeOilleánTub:"¢3.80",
        OilleánTubSmall:"¢2.50",
    };    
    
//printout object key:value in a table
   document.write("<table id=myTable><tr><th>Name</th><th>Cost</th></tr>");
    for(var key in dunMenu) {
       document.write("<tr><td>",key,"</td><td>",dunMenu[key],"</td></tr>");
    };
    document.write("</table>");

}


function cityArray(){
    var cityMenu={
        CitrusCrepe:"¢3.50",
        NutellaCrepe:"¢4",
        StrawberryChoc:"¢2.50",
    };    
    
//printout object key:value in a table
   document.write("<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Cost</th></tr>");
    for(var key in cityMenu) {
       document.write("<tr><td>",key,"</td><td>",cityMenu[key],"</td></tr>");
    };
    document.write("</table>");

}


function orderOnline(){
    var orderMenu={
        BuenoWaffleCone:"¢4.50",
        OilleánMess:"¢5.50",
        OilleánNoffee:"¢5.50",
        SnickerBockerGlory:"¢5.50",
        TwixFix:"¢5.50",
    };    

//printout object key:value in a table
    document.getElementById("myTable");
   document.write("<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Cost</th></tr>");
    for(var key in orderMenu) {
       document.write("<tr><td>",key,"</td><td>",orderMenu[key],"</td></tr>");
    };
    document.write("</table>");

}
```

```html
</header>

<div class="button-group">
    <button class="button button-primary" onclick="dundrumArray()">Dun Drum</button>
    <button class="button button-primary" onclick="cityArray()">City Center</button>
    <button class="button button-primary" onclick="orderOnline()">Order Online</button>
</div>
<div id="myTable"></div>


</main>
```

Currently, when I push one of the buttons it jumps to a new page.
I'm quite new to this sort of stuff. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is the `<button>` inside a `<form>` element?

Comment: no. should they be?

Comment: No, you said when you click a button you go to a new page, so that's the first Q&A question that has to be asked.  `<button>` elements in a `<form>` by default submit forms which cause page transfers.

Comment: Sorry- if you want to make it not jump to a new page, you have to make sure the button is `type=button` or preventDefault() or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the innerHTML of the target element with text, like this:

```js
function cityArray(){
    var cityMenu={
        CitrusCrepe:"¢3.50",
        NutellaCrepe:"¢4",
        StrawberryChoc:"¢2.50",
    };    
    
//printout object key:value in a table
let txt = "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Cost</th></tr>";
    for(var key in cityMenu) {
       txt += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td><td>" + cityMenu[key] + "</td></tr>";
    };
    document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = txt;

}
```

```html
<div class="button-group">
    <button type="button" class="button button-primary" onclick="cityArray()">City Center</button>
</div>
<div id="myTable"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

thereis plenty JS methods to deal withe tables:

```js
const menu = 
  { dunMenu : 
      { OilleánTub      : "¢3.50"
      , DeluxeOilleánTub: "¢3.80"
      , OilleánTubSmall : "¢2.50"
      } 
  , cityMenu : 
      { CitrusCrepe    : "¢3.50"
      , NutellaCrepe   : "¢4"
      , StrawberryChoc : "¢2.50"
      } 
  , orderMenu : 
      { BuenoWaffleCone    : "¢4.50"
      , OilleánMess        : "¢5.50"
      , OilleánNoffee      : "¢5.50"
      , SnickerBockerGlory : "¢5.50"
      , TwixFix            : "¢5.50"
      } 
    }
const div4Table = document.querySelector('div#myTable')
  ,   byMenu    = document.querySelector('div.button-group')
  ;
function makeTable(tbName)
  {
  div4Table.innerHTML = "" // clear Anything

  let t  = div4Table.appendChild(  document.createElement('table'))
    , tH = t.createTHead()
    , tB = t.createTBody()
    ;
  nH = tH.insertRow()
  nH.insertCell().textContent = 'Name'
  nH.insertCell().textContent = 'Cost'

  Object.entries( menu[tbName]).forEach(([k,v])=>
    {
    let nRow = tB.insertRow()
    nRow.insertCell().textContent = k
    nRow.insertCell().textContent = v
    })
  }
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: .5em;
}
thead {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #978aec;
  text-align: center;
}
td {
  padding: .2em .7em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-group">
  <button class="button button-primary" onclick="makeTable('dunMenu')">Dun Drum</button>
  <button class="button button-primary" onclick="makeTable('cityMenu')">City Center</button>
  <button class="button button-primary" onclick="makeTable('orderMenu')">Order Online</button>
</div>
<div id="myTable"></div>
```